# Screencap command returns image with 0 bytes

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm using Kotlin and trying to capture an screenshot using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png")`, the image is produced in my folder but the image contains 0 bytes, and no exception is showed. What am I doing wrong?

- minSdkVersion 22
- targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: exec() returns an instance of `Process`. Consider reading its `outputStream` and `errorStream` to get process output and see which errors happen. My guess: applications do not have permissions which ADB has.